# java.sql.SQLException: method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I would like to connect to SQLite database using SQLite using HikariCP.
But I get an error when I try to run a query.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement
    at StatementUtility.wrapException(StatementUtility.java:110)
    at StatementUtility.executeUpdate(StatementUtility.java:101)
    at Database.createTables(Database.java:27)
    at Database.<init>(Database.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Hikari Connection Setup:

```java
public Client () {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setPoolName("AuthMeSQLitePool");
    config.setDriverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlite:I:/data.db");
    config.setMaxLifetime(60000);
    config.setIdleTimeout(45000);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
}
```

StatementUtility.java:

```java
public <R> R executeQuery(String sql, ThrowingConsumer<PreparedStatement> cfg, ThrowingFunction<ResultSet, R, SQLException> op) {
    return wrapException(sql, s -> {
        cfg.accept(s);
        return op.apply(s.executeQuery());
    });
}

public int executeUpdate(String sql, ThrowingConsumer<PreparedStatement> cfg) {
    return wrapException(sql, s -> {
        cfg.accept(s);
        return s.executeUpdate();
    });
}

public <R> R executeQuery(String sql, ThrowingFunction<ResultSet, R, SQLException> op) {
    return wrapException(sql, s -> op.apply(s.executeQuery(sql)));
}

public int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    return wrapException(sql, s -> s.executeUpdate(sql));
}

private <T> T wrapException(String sql, @NotNull ThrowingFunction<PreparedStatement, T, SQLException> operation) {
    try(Connection connection = getConnection()){
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            return operation.apply(statement);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T> {

    @Override
    default void accept(final T elem) {
        try {
            acceptThrows(elem);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    void acceptThrows(T elem) throws Exception;
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T input) throws E;
}
```

It works with native query statement execution, so it is not a connection related problem. Any idea?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for Statement.executeUpdate(String). You want to call `s.executeUpdate()`, as you've already provided the SQL to `prepareStatement`.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS they are using parameterless prepared statements, as far as I can tell. i.e. the DDL is a static string.

Comment: private <T> T wrapException(String sql, @NotNull ThrowingFunction<Statement, T, SQLException> operation) {
        try(Connection connection = getConnectionType().getConnection()){
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                return operation.apply(statement);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

You mean to change PreparedStatement to Statement like this ?

Comment: That should work, yes. But when you want to provide parameters to your statements you should use prepared statements.

Comment: Yes cause with this method i'm unable to parse PreparedStatement in parameters

Comment: But none of your functions have parameters, just static SQL, so `createStatement` is fine for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of your methods call `executeQuery(String)` or `executeUpdate(String)` on `PreparedStatement`, and this is not allowed by the JDBC API. Conforming implementations are required to throw a `SQLException` if this happens.

As documented on [`Statement.executeQuery(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine):

> **Throws:** 
> `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed `Statement`, the given SQL statement produces anything other than a single `ResultSet` object, **the method is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`**

The same is documented for other `execute` methods on `Statement`.

You either need to use `executeQuery()` or `executeUpdate()`, or you need to use a `Statement` instead of a `PreparedStatement`.